# Calendar date x-scale values result in incorrect plotting in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

0I'm trying to plot a value for each day in a calendar month (May 2013), where dates form the x axis. The data is pulled out of an HTML table that provides a calendar in which there are 35 entries, like in a desktop calendar such as iCal. So x-scale tick data looks like this:

```
   var xtix = ["28", "29", "30", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "1"];
```

It's all string data. Meanwhile the x-scale range data looks like this:

```
var range = [40, 56, 71, 87, 103, 119, 134, 150, 166, 181, 197, 213, 229, 244, 260, 276, 291, 307, 323, 339, 354, 370, 386, 401, 417, 433, 449, 464, 480, 496, 511, 527, 543, 559, 574];
```

I'm creating the x axis with this code:

```
var xscale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(xtix).range(range);
var xaxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xscale).orient('bottom').ticks(xtix);
svg.append('g').attr('class', 'axis xaxis').attr('transform', 'translate(0,'+(h-20)+')').call(xaxis);
```

One problem is that the ticks aren't displayed correctly on the axis. Everything is fine up until the 27th of May, then the following tick is 31, then that's it. It's like d3 is ignoring duplicates in the array. Here's an image:

[image]

Also, when I plot my points using the following:

```
dataset[0].pointdata = [[40, 8], [56, 8], [71, 6], [87, 6], [103, 4], [119, 3], [134, 5], [150, 5], [166, 5], [181, 4], [197, 5], [213, 6], [229, 6], [244, 5], [260, 5], [276, 4], [291, 3], [307, 4], [323, 6], [339, 6], [354, 7], [370, 6], [386, 6], [401, 4], [417, 3], [433, 5], [449, 4], [464, 4], [480, 4], [496, 6], [511, 7], [527, 7], [543, 8], [559, 7], [574, 5]];
var g = svg.append('svg:g').attr('class', 'pathgroup').attr('transform', 'translate(0,'+ypadding+')');
g.selectAll('circle')
  .data(dataset[j].pointdata)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) { return xscale(d[0]); })
  .attr('cy', function(d) { return yscale(d[1]); })
  .attr('r', 3)
  .attr('stroke-width', 2)
  .attr('class', 'color'+dataset[j].color);
```

The points are displayed in the graph in the wrong order. The first four data points are placed at the end of the graph (where there are no ticks) and then the fifth onward are displayed on the existing ticks in sequence.

I'm also plotting a week view, which works great, using basically the same method but with the xtix variable containing this:

```
var xtix = ["May 5", "May 6", "May 7", "May 8", "May 9", "May 10", "May 11"];
```

Which doesn't seem to confuse d3 at all. This is really odd, really hoping someone can help.

Comment: Have you tried using the built in time formatting? https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting
Create date objects and just print the day of month on the axis.

Comment: When I tried that, the result was slightly worse: the ticks on the x scale now only go up to 27 and stop there.